# How to use regex placeholder in PyCharm replace function

Tags: python, regex, pycharm

I have a Python file where are many lines like this one:

```
df['A'] = df.T + df.N / df.R
```

I want to replace each `df.something` occurances with `df['something']`, so the above line becomes:

```
df['A'] = df['T'] + df['N'] / df['R']
```

I activate the replace functionality with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then I tick the `Reg̲ex` option and I successfully highlight every occurrances by searching for `df.[A-Z]`, as `[A-Z]` stands for each `T`, `N`, `R` and so on, as it is a placeholder.
I do not know how to use the same placeholder in the "Replace with" box and, therefore, what to write: if I reuse `[A-Z]` (image below) as placeholder and write `df.['[A-Z]']` I get this:

```
df['A'] = df['[A-Z]'] + df['[A-Z]'] / df['[A-Z]']
```

[image]

What should I write as a placeholder in the bottom box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to search for

```
df\.([A-Z]+)
```

And replace this with

```
df\["$1"\]
```

---

Then

```
df['A'] = df.T + df.N / df.R
```

becomes

```
df['A'] = df["T"] + df["N"] / df["R"]
```

You need to enable the regex mechanism (last one on the right). Remember that `[`, `]` and `.` are meta characters within regex, `$1` is the first captured group content.

---

For the other direction, you could use

```
df\['([^']+)'\]
```

and replace this with

```
df.$1
```

This will only work with single quotes though. For double and single quotes use

```
df\[(['"])(.+?)\1\]
```

and replace it with

```
df.$2
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked! And, what if I want to do the opposite replacement?